# Get Current logged in user details from Azure AD in Web API controller

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

NET Core 3.0 Web API in which earlier I was using Windows Authentication. So in my controller this was the way I was following to get current logged in user details.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);
```

I have setup everything in Azure portal and in my App for Azure AD based authentication. Thus when I starts the application it login successful and returning back to my page since I have set **replyurl** in the portal.

But on returning back I am not getting anything in **ctx** variable. I really believe when using Azure AD this could be some other way to achieve this. Please help me on solving that.

Comment: are you usuing azure app service?

Comment: Yes, Azure app service

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fetch the details with

```
ViewBag.Name = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
```